# Custom Post type - how to get checkbox to update meta field to null

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have 7 meta fields for a custom post type in Wordpress. These 7 in particular are days of the week (Sunday thru Saturday) and have checkboxes for each. I've successfully gotten the checkbox to POST when the value is "On", however when I return to the edit page and try to deselect, the value stays the same in the database.

Here is what I have for each item input:

```
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="sunday" <?php if( $meta_sunday == true ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>" /> Sunday<br /></li>
```

And my update lines:

```
if(!isset($_POST["sunday"])):
    return $post;
    endif;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "sunday", $_POST["sunday"] );
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, an unchecked checkbox is not set in $_POST. You'd have to empty the meta for the checkboxes that are not set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears the post meta is not being cleared for 'sunday' when the checkbox is unchecked.

```
If( isset($_POST['sunday']) ){
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "sunday", $_POST["sunday"] );
}else{
    delete_post_meta($post->ID, "sunday");
}
return $post;
```

Or you can set the value to false

```
If( isset($_POST['sunday']) ){
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "sunday", true );
}else{
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "sunday", false );
}
return $post;
```

Comment: Just consolidating your code a little, `update_post_meta($post->ID, "sunday", isset($_POST['sunday']) );`

Comment: Thanks @MatthewBoynes and Ryan Meier - this worked perfect

Answer (score 2):

Unchecked checkboxes are not set in the $_POST, so you'd have to empty their meta field.

Something like this should work :

```
 $sunday = ( isset( $_POST['sunday'] ) ) ? $_POST['sunday'] : "";
 update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sunday', $sunday );
```

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked checkboxes are not set in the $_POST, they are set in $_REQUEST,
you can set checkbox value of custom post type like this:

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['inprint'] ) ) {
   update_post_meta($post_id, '_inprint', TRUE);
 } else {
   update_post_meta($post_id, '_inprint', FALSE);
 }
```

and get checkbox value like this:

```
global $post;

$inprint= get_post_meta($post->ID, '_inprint', true);

<input type="checkbox" name="inprint" value='1'<?php checked(1, $inprint); ?> />
```